# Facebook Login always erroring out on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I have a simple app where I am integrating Facebook Login via Facebook SDK on iOS. I have the following code segment when the user taps on "Signup With FaceBook" button :

```
// Open a session showing the user the login UI
// You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
```

This works on most of the devices, but on some devices, this errors out with the NSError coming back as :

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" 
UserInfo=0x178467a40 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, 
com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts 
Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied 
  app cannot request publish permissions without having being 
  installed previously."
```

The error says that I need to ask for publish permission, but I am asking for "public_profile" and "email" what am i missing?

Update: It looks like on the devices this fails is where the user has signed in to FaceBook in Settings. I would expect the Facebook SDK to do the right thing, instead it somehow does the above.. Is there something else I need to make this work? without implementing both SocialKit and FaceBook SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after lots of experimentation, asking for the "public_profile" in the permissions somehow makes iOS ask for read/write permission in the request and that triggers the error above. - There are various threads on asking for both read/write permission failing.

Asking for just "email" should be sufficient as that implicitly get the public profile.